# How do I trigger an alert/swal function once and not repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular.

I have an app with two variables that indicate the status of a financial transaction. 
The variables are: `tab1TrxMessage` that stores any **messages** and `tab1TrxStatus` that indicate a transactions status either being: **Failed**, **is successful** or **is pending**. When a transaction has failed, I would like the user to recieve a **swal** alert/notification similar to this:

```
swal({
       title:'Error!',
       text: 'Warning... Transaction failed!',
       type: 'error',
       confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
       confirmButtonColor: '#ff754f'
     });
```

Currently, my code looks like this:

**../component.html**

```
<div class="sign-btn text-center">
  <a class="btn btn-lg text-white">
    <span *ngIf="tab1TrxMessage">{{tab1TrxMessage}}</span>
    <span *ngIf="!tab1TrxMessage && tab1TrxStatus != 'Success'">Failed</span>
    <span *ngIf="transactionFailed()">Failed</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

With specific attention on the `transactionFailed()` function...

**../component.ts**

```
public transactionFailed() {

    if(this.tab1TrxMessage == 'Failed: Cancelled by User' && this.tab1TrxStatus != 'Success') {

        console.log("You are in transactionFailed!")

        swal({
           title:'Error!',
           text: 'Warning... Transaction failed!',
           type: 'error',
           confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
           confirmButtonColor: '#ff754f'
         });

         return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The code above, when a transaction fails yields: `You are in transactionFailed!` multiples times in the browser console...

[image: console print out]

...and so does the **swal** alert with `Warning... Transaction failed!` repeatedly popping up.

Is there a better way to resolve this so that the **swal** alert only displays **ONCE** per failed transaction?

Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a counter which will run your code only once. For eg.

```js
failedTransactionCntr = 0;
public transactionFailed() {

    if(this.tab1TrxMessage == 'Failed: Cancelled by User' && this.tab1TrxStatus != 'Success') {

        console.log("You are in transactionFailed!")
        if (this.failedTransactionCntr == 0) {
          swal({
           title:'Error!',
           text: 'Warning... Transaction failed!',
           type: 'error',
           confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
           confirmButtonColor: '#ff754f'
         });
         this.failedTransactionCntr ++;
        }
         return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens due to the your change detection strategy and method `transactionFailed()` function will be called every time Angular runs change detection. The reason why it happens is because updating DOM is part of change detection and Angular needs to call `transactionFailed()` to know what value to use for DOM update.

You can change `changeDetectionStrategy` to `onPush` to avoid `transactionFailed()` to be called multiple times.

```
@Component({
 selector: 'your-component',
 templateUrl: './your.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./your.component.css'],
 changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush // this line
})

export class YourComponent {

}
```

However, it is necessary to manually call method `detectChanges()` when you want the change detection to run:

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.ref.detach();
}

start() {
    this.fooVariable = 'This is a foo vaiable';
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

[You can read more about Change detection strategies here](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/09/27/angular-performances-part-4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in it being valid only once, you can very well use a flag.
For example:

```js
lFlagtransfailed = false; 
public transactionFailed() {

    if(this.tab1TrxMessage == 'Failed: Cancelled by User' && this.tab1TrxStatus != 'Success' && lFlagtransfailed == false) { 

        console.log("You are in transactionFailed!")
        lFlagtransfailed = true;
        swal({
           title:'Error!',
           text: 'Warning... Transaction failed!',
           type: 'error',
           confirmButtonText: 'Ok',
           confirmButtonColor: '#ff754f'
         });

         return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```